# Is DotNetNuke currently ADA 508 compliant?

Tags: .net, asp.net, accessibility, dotnetnuke, section508

Is DotNetNuke currently ADA 508 compliant?

I realize that it depends on how you use it, but I'm talking about out of the box, core modules, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since DNN runs their own software on their site, just run a 508 validator such as section508.info on dotnetnuke.com

Their front page has some parsing errors and other minor issues, but overall, it passes compliance.

Then I ran it on some of their other pages, and it failed, so I guess it depends on which modules are used.

If you find a module out of compliance, you might be able to find a replacement created by someone else, that is compliant.

Answer (score 0):

I've used it for clients in the past who cared about accessibility - it's OK. Not perfect, some small issues, but generally OK. I'm not sure if there are any more compliant systems on .NET.